# How to learn 4v4?

Tags: starcraft-2

I play mostly 4v4 games (as random with random people) and I'm stuck in the gold league with 765 wins. I'm looking for any guides or tips, how to progress in 4v4. Progamers usually stream only 1v1 games and the majority of tutorials are dedicated to 1v1 as well. Are there any tutorials focused on teamplay?

Comment: Yeah, as for getting better. Really, the only way you can do this is by 1v1s. You can't measure any kind of skill off of team games alone.

Comment: as zerg take 3 bases fast as you can xD, then pop units

Comment: 3 bases in a 4v4? Joking, right? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4v4 games are considered "fun" games, so usually everybody tries to cheese somehow. The game is definitely not balanced for 4v4s.

You should stop playing this mode competitively and go for 2v2 if you really like team games.

The problem with huge games like 4v4 is that there are way too many permutations to consider. In 1v1 there are 3 matchups you have to learn, if your race remains the same. In 2v2 there are already 6 or even more if you play random team. You get the idea.

But if you really want to progress in 4v4 here are some tips:

- Try to get generally better at the game. Micro / Macro. There are occasions where your team will get slaughtered and you have to carry the game.
- Try to coordinate your strategy with your team. All rush for tier 1 units at the same time etc.
- At least one of your team should try to get an early expansion.
- Always scout for cheese (cannons / zergling rush etc.)
- Always assume that Protoss will go for Dark Templar eventually.

Learning something new works best like this:

- Limit the parameters that can change. Use the same race on the same map with the same team, instead of mixing everything.
- Try to execute the same build over and over again.
- Watch your replays and understand your problems. Is your money low, do you have high APM, are you producing all the time etc.

Most of the 1v1 mechanics work also in 4v4.

Answer (score 1):

To be a better player means to be able to play reactively to the situation in the game. In 1v1, this means scouting your opponent and preparing for what's coming, or playing more greedy because you know you can get away with it. In 4v4, knowing what your teammates are doing is almost as important as knowing what your opponent is doing. Fortunately you have complete vision of your teammates, and thus playing "reactively" in 4v4 is much easier. This will make you a better teammate, and give you some control over your success in random 4v4.

- If you see one of them heading out to suicide their huge mid-game army (common in low level team games), go try to support him as long as you can retreat if necessary.
- If one of them is successfully cannon rushing, maybe it's safe for you to take an expo.
- If you enter the game and someone says "rushing to battlecruisers", stay low-tier one-base and help him defend.
- If an opponent is massing colossus, and nobody else on your team has begun viking production, take the initiative. Announce it as well.
- When you need to retreat, announce it so you don't leave your allies hanging.
- If all your allies are doing some low-level rush, maybe you have an opportunity to fast expand and mass a high tech unit, or join in the rush too.
- If an ally is massing a unit that doesn't shoot air, consider massing a complementary unit like marines or stalkers. Mass colossus is strong, but colossus + viking is basically unbeatable.

It can be annoying to cooperate with bad players ("battlecruiser rush" for example), but in the interest of winning, it's necessary to swallow your pride and proactively carry the game for your team.

4v4 is extremely volatile, where luck is more of a factor than skill (getting good teammates, chemistry between teammates, map positioning, 4v1 rushes...). If you want to have control over your success, you should stick to 1v1, 2v2, or make a predefined 4v4 team with 3 friends (instead of having random teammates). I honestly don't even know how battle.net can give an accurate MMR for the 4v4 format.

1v1 is really the place where you improve as a player though. If I were you, I would play 1v1 to get better, and 4v4 to put that skill to use. Maybe set a rule for yourself, like you always warm up with a couple 1v1 matches before going to 4v4.